# How to add debugging capabilities to a custom programming language

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging, dbg

I'm using a custom language. It's a procedural language; it has variables, functions, namespaces, expressions etc, but it lacks an important feature: debugging.

It has a compiler that generates a byte code and a runtime runner that runs it (like the the jvm in Java).

How can I add debugging to it?

Where should I start?

Should I extend an existing debugger to this language or create a debugger from scratch?

I need support in Intellij, at least.

Thanks.